# How to use React Native Package in a TS based library?

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-native-module

I'm creating a custom library for React Native. I initiated the library using react-native-create-library. The library has not any native code. It's just written in typescript. At some places, I need to use react-native packages like react-native-bip39 and react-native-libsodium. But when I import any one of them it doesn't work, instead, it gives error that .default.function() is undefined or null.

How I can import such libraries into my project.